# How to obtain absolute differences after predictions (with lsmeans) from a logistic model

Tags: r, lsmeans

I am using a logistic model for a binary outcome with three independent predictors. After adjusting the model, I want to estimate predictions of my outcome (y) using marginal means (lsmeans) and contrast such predictions. However, I noticed that the contrasts are done in the relative scale (ratios) instead of the absolute scale (differences) if the model that I use is a logistic model. Does anyone have any idea how I can get absolute differences for the contrasts of predictions (using lsmeans)obtained from a logistic model?

Here is an example:

```
library(lsmeans)

#### Creating my Data
y<- rbinom(10000, 1, .02)
a<- sample(c(2005:2014), 10000, replace = T, prob = c(0.10023452, 0.09867466,
                                                       0.09869976, 0.09880913,
                                                       0.09903145, 0.10275898,
                                                       0.10470253, 0.09909241, 
                                                       0.09889877, 0.09909779))
b<- rbinom(10000, 1, 0.57)
c<- sample(c(1:4), 10000, replace = T, prob = c(0.61969154, 0.12735996, 0.16385892, 0.08908958))


df<-data.frame(cbind(y, a, b, c))
df$a<-factor(df$a)
df$b<-factor(df$b)
df$c<-factor(df$c)

#### Logistic Model

m1<-glm(y~a*b*c, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"), data = df)
summary(m1)

#### LSMEANS prediction
m1.ls<-lsmeans(m1, "a", by=c("b", "c"), infer=c(TRUE, TRUE), level=.95, 
    data=df)

#### Checking my predictions in the log odds scale
summary(m1.ls)

#### Checking my predictions in the probability scale
summary(m1.ls, type = "response")

m1.ctr.odds<-summary(contrast(m1.ls, infer=c(TRUE, TRUE), by=c("b", "c"), 
                           level=.95, method="revpairwise"))

m1.ctr.prob<-summary(contrast(m1.ls, infer=c(TRUE, TRUE), by=c("b", "c"), 
                           level=.95, method="revpairwise"), type = "response")


#### Contrasts are in the log odds ratio scale. NOTE this are RATIOS of log odds
m1.ctr.odds

#### Contrasts are in the probability scale. NOTE this are RATIOS of probabilities
m1.ctr.prob #### I would like these contrasts to be absolute differences (substractions)
```

Best,

L

Comment: Converting odds ratios to absolute differences requires you to specify the absolute level of risk in the control/reference group. Then you can convert to a relative risk/absolute risk reduction [e.g. like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio#Relation_to_relative_risk). Do you want to just use the observed event rates in each reference group for this?

Comment: Hey @Marius Thank you so much for your answer, and I think you are right concerning specifying the baseline risk to convert the odds to risks. However, I am not sure how to do this in the context of incorporating it to the function "contrast" in ¨lsmeans¨.